# Синхронизация двух+ баз данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть сайт для которого нужно сделать английскую версию. Проблема в том, что он уже почти реализован, и новую локализацию так просто не впихнуть. -- БД никак не спроектирована под это дело.

Простая идея - использовать две БД для русской и английской локализации, но тут тоже возникает проблема - нужно будет как-то синхронизировать новые записи между двумя БД, с таким условием, что все данные будут идентичны (идентификаторы, связи, настройки, представления), отличатся будут только текстовые поля, и некоторые данные которые отвечают за локализацию сайта.

Существуют ли какой нибудь механизм на уровне БД(интересует MySQL, ну или хотя бы Postgres), который может синхронизировать данные так, как я описал выше?

UPD: Может так случится, что заказчик захочет добавить еще один язык, и тогда уже будет три БД.

Comment: Сделайте view вместо таблиц которые нужно "дублировать", если всё происходит в пределах одного сервера, если серверов несколько(свой под каждую локаль) - репликация.

Comment: Интересно, кто будет транслировать тексты в новых записях, при их копировании в  другую БД. Обычно язык затрагивает всего несколько таблиц, отвечающих за вывод пользовательского интерфейса. А их можно просто триггерами копировать. Но у вас возникает другая проблема (причем при любом способе "синхронизации") - поля, которые к языку отношения не имеют. При изменении такого поля в одной БД вам придется не забывать его копировать, при этом не затрагивая языковые. В общем мне кажется, что с несколькими БД у вас проблем будет больше, чем с аккуратной доработкой одной БД и кода под мультиязычность